# Installation Ecobee3 Smart Thermostat Confusion

Tags: electrical, hvac, furnace, thermostat

[image]

So Ecobee' website says my configuration is compatible but after looking at my wires (Im not an AC guy) I have lots of questions as the wiring doesnt just align perfectly. Im assuming because my unit us 10+ years old and things have changed. So here are my questions..

1. My old unit has R but the Ecobee only has Rc and Rh. Do I need to 
   jump this to both?
2. My Y is jumped to W1 as you can see in the photo. Does the same need to occur on the Ecobee?
3. W2 is connected to both W2 and E but the Ecobee doesnt even have E. Is this needed or am I out if luck?
4. Lastly, O is on the Ecobee but labeled O/B. Is this ok to just connect to?

Sorry for the list but if anyone can take the time to explain Id be more than greatful. Im also thinking that the site may be wrong and its just not compatible. Please let me know if so.If additional pictures are needed I can provide them.

Comment: `Y` tells the heat pump to turn on. `O` tells the heat pump which mode to operate in (heat/cool).  `W` turns on auxiliary heat. `G` turns on the blower. `R` is 24 volt hot, `C` is 24 volt neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Ecobee3 automatically handles the Rh vs Rc thing, so just connect your R wire to either Rh or Rc.
2. You can connect Y to Y only on the Ecobee3 and configure it for heat pump operation
3. W2 connects to W1 on the Ecobee -- this is your axuiliary heat
4. Yes, O on your old 'stat does connect to O/B on the Ecobee.

See [this diagram](https://www.ecobee.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/ecobee_Wiring_HeatPump1.pdf) for more info.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly! Appreciate you sharing tge knowledge.